# Convert Mat to Bitmap by opencv

Tags: android, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to convert Mat rectangle from onCameraFrame to bitmap then send the bitmap to ocr function because i need to make the ocr works on real-time on ROI according to rectangle. I tried these lines:

```
        Mat mgray= inputFrame.gray();

        Mat grayInnerWindow = mgray.submat(100, 100 +500, 150, 200 + 50);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
        rgbaInnerWindow.release();


        Size sizeGray = grayInnerWindow.size();
        int rowss = (int) sizeGray.height;
        int colss = (int) sizeGray.width;

        Mat tmp =  new Mat(colss, rowss, CvType.CV_8UC4);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbaInnerWindow, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA, 4);
       Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);                
        ImageView Img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_manipulations_activity_surface_view);               
        Img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but when i run it terminated.

Comment: terminated **why**?! Logcat needed here ...

Answer (score 0):

you are releasing rgbaInnerWindow, then you re-use it as input to cvtColor.

yep, that will burn, rgbaInnerWindow is invalid/empty now..

also, why all those cvtColor calls ? can't you just pass an 8bit grayscale image to your ocr?

(converting a 4channel, all grayscale image from rgba to bgra is utterly useless)